# Get all tables from database and loop through each table using C#, Linq query and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, entity-framework

I have a SQL Server 2012 database with 12 tables (excluding look up tables). I am using Entity Framework and trying to query. I am able to query a table

```
ClientEntities dc = new ClientEntities();
var query = from client1 in dc.CLIENTTable
            where client1.CLIENT_ID == txtId.Text
            select client1;
```

Above works for 1 table but I need to do it for all the 12 tables. Is there a way to do it in loop?

Comment: Querying all tables doesn't sound like a job for an ORM like EF. It sounds more like an ad-hoc query tool. Much as I'm not a fan of DataTable, it is probably a better tool for this job,

Answer (score 0):

you can get a list of table with SqlConnection.GetSchema 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/a2953687-ff78-47a6-9071-ceac64728d9a/

after that iterate this list with your query (which became a subquery)
Best regards